# use of ''as '' in sentence below while evaluating something

Tags: prepositions

Is use of ''as'' correct in sentence below:

> Authorized person evaluated my appeal as out of scope .

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

But, as it is, the sentence is missing an article or something.

**An** authorized person evaluated my appeal as out of scope.

Comment: Okay. Can i say An authorized person find my appeal out of scope ? I mean aren’t there two meaning in this sentence ?

Comment: No. The reason is the do not passively 'find' the appeal. They actively 'rule' it. So you can say '...ruled my appeal as out of scope', '...evaluated my appeal as out of scope', '...declared my appeal as out of scope'... something like that.

Comment: I mean can i use make this sentence as is the case with the structure find something+adjective?

Comment: If you really want to use 'found' you can. But you cannot use 'find' as it should be past tense. In my opinion, you should use an active verb.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence will be grammatical if you put an article before "authorized person".

If you evaluate someone or something as someone or something, you judge the value of someome or something in a certain way. For example:

I evaluated him as a professional dancer.

They evaluated your answer as satisfactory.